# cakePHP: Major lag issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, lag, php-5.6, cakephp-2.5

We’re having major lag issue while updating production status and updating production quantity. We’re using JQUERY AJAX post method to do that work. Things work smartly and with good speed, when we comment-out the function “recalculateProduction()” inside the “AppController.php” file for both updating status and updating quantity.

**User Experience:**
The application picks up orders of finished food products from a tab delimited file on the server and then figures out how much raw material is needed to make the product based on recipe data. The specific part of the system that is lagging is where the admin can manually adjust the quantity of the customer orders. So, for example, the admin may decide to reduce the order quantity of pasta salad from Acme from 50 lbs to 40 lbs. The application then recalculates all of the necessary raw material as a result of that quantity change. Currently, it is taking upwards of two minutes for everything to be recalculated when a single quantity is changed.

The function “recalculateProduction()” consist of huge calculation, updating records of different DB tables and deleting records from different tables.

```
public function recalculateProduction($production_id, $action_performed_by){
$this->loadModel(‘Production’);
$this->loadModel(‘ProductionItem’);
$this->loadModel(‘ProductionOrder’);
$this->loadModel(‘ProductionRecipe’);
$this->loadModel(‘ProductionIngredient’);
$this->loadModel(‘ProductionRawMaterial’);
$this->loadModel(‘ProductionOrderProductionRecipe’);
$this->loadModel(‘ProductionOrderProductionIngredient’);
$this->loadModel(‘ProductionOrderProductionRawMaterial’);

$production = $this->Production->read(null, $production_id);

$this->ProductionItem->updateAll(array('order_case_qty'=>0, 'quantity_lbs'=>0, 'production_case_qty'=>0), array('ProductionItem.production_id'=>$production_id));
$this->ProductionRecipe->updateAll(array('qty_lbs'=>0, 'batch_qty_lbs'=>0, 'batches'=>0, 'batch_size'=>0, 'actual_lbs'=>0, 'percent_yield'=>0), array('ProductionRecipe.production_id'=>$production_id));
$this->ProductionIngredient->updateAll(array('qty_lbs'=>0), array('ProductionIngredient.production_id'=>$production_id));
$this->ProductionRawMaterial->updateAll(array('qty_lbs'=>0), array('ProductionRawMaterial.production_id'=>$production_id));

$this->ProductionOrderProductionRecipe->deleteAll(array('ProductionOrderProductionRecipe.production_order_id IN (SELECT id FROM imrp_production_order ProductionOrder WHERE ProductionOrder.production_id='.$production_id.')'));
$this->ProductionOrderProductionIngredient->deleteAll(array('ProductionOrderProductionIngredient.production_order_id IN (SELECT id FROM imrp_production_order ProductionOrder WHERE ProductionOrder.production_id='.$production_id.')'));
$this->ProductionOrderProductionRawMaterial->deleteAll(array('ProductionOrderProductionRawMaterial.production_order_id IN (SELECT id FROM imrp_production_order ProductionOrder WHERE ProductionOrder.production_id='.$production_id.')'));

$this->ProductionOrder->recursive = 0;
$production_orders = $this->ProductionOrder->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('ProductionOrder.status IN (0, 1)', 'ProductionOrder.production_id'=>$production_id)));
if(count($production_orders)>0){
    foreach($production_orders as $production_order){
        $this->processOrderDetails($production_id, $production_order['ProductionOrder']['item_id'], $production_order['ProductionOrder']['id'], $production['Production']['production_date'], $production_order['ProductionOrder']['quantity_lbs'], $production_order['ProductionOrder']['quantity_cases'], $action_performed_by);
    }
}

$this->ProductionItem->deleteAll(array('ProductionItem.production_id'=>$production_id, 'ProductionItem.order_case_qty'=>0.00, 'ProductionItem.quantity_lbs'=>0.00, 'ProductionItem.production_case_qty'=>0.00));
$this->ProductionRecipe->deleteAll(array('ProductionRecipe.production_id'=>$production_id, 'ProductionRecipe.qty_lbs'=>0.00, 'ProductionRecipe.batch_qty_lbs'=>0.00000, 'ProductionRecipe.batches'=>0.00000, 'ProductionRecipe.batch_size'=>0, 'ProductionRecipe.actual_lbs'=>0.00, 'ProductionRecipe.percent_yield'=>0.000));
$this->ProductionIngredient->deleteAll(array('ProductionIngredient.production_id'=>$production_id, 'ProductionIngredient.qty_lbs'=>0.00));
$this->ProductionRawMaterial->deleteAll(array('ProductionRawMaterial.production_id'=>$production_id, 'ProductionRawMaterial.qty_lbs'=>0.00));

$this->processProductionRecipes($production_id, $action_performed_by);
}
```

I can investigate using stored procedures, but I was hoping to be able to salvage the work I’ve already done. My thinking is that because the PHP framework queries all relationship data in a single query. To stop fetching relationship data we applied the “recursive = 0” but that has not fixed the issue. Any suggestions?

*NOTE:* We’re only dealing with a few hundred records. At most, once in production, we may be dealing with several thousand records at most. We're using PHP Version: 5.6.35 and CakePHP Version: 2.5.7.

Thanks.

Comment: Profile your code using xdebug and your SQL queries. This can't be really answered without doing that. Also why is this in the AppController? All of this should be in a model object, but clearly not in a controller. The code doesn't really look good either. The foreach() there alone makes me think there is a lot slowness coming from there because it runs very likely over a lot records. Is this somehow unit tested at all? Are the tests as well slow? If you can't profile it find a CakePHP / php expert who can. :)

Comment: Have you also tried optimizing your database? may be index are missing for select, or there are multiple index on table that are being updated.

Comment: Using DebugKit you can easily see which of the queries are taking so long.

Comment: Also note that inserting `$production_id` directly into an SQL snippet is a possible SQL injection vulnerability!